# How to write a function to search for a string within an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, search

This is what I have so far:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    printf("%d", i);
    found = strpbrk(nameholder[i], searchterm);
    if(strpbrk(nameholder[i], searchterm) == searchterm){
        printf("found\n");
        foundwhere = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}// end for
```

When I run the program, the strpbrk function finds the string, but for some reason it never triggers the if statement. What am I missing?

Comment: What is your test input?

Comment: You're using the wrong operator. `==` is for numerical equality.

Comment: I got it working it was a combination of different things, using strcmp() instead of strpbrk() was the first step in figuring it out though. When i used strcmp() it would return 1 as the result, so then i realize an extra character was being added to the original string input. So thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I correctly understood (your description is vague) what you are trying to do, then you seem to be using a wrong function.

Quoting cpp docs on strpbrk:

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of any of the characters that are part of str2, or a null pointer if there are no matches.

That's not what you want it to do, right? You should be looking at `strcpm` function.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Your code should look like:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){ 
    if(strcmp(nameholder[i], searchterm) == 0){
        printf("found\n");
        foundwhere = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}// end for
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk , `strpbrk()` is for

> `const char* strpbrk( const char* dest, const char* str );`
>   Finds the first character in byte string pointed to by `dest`, that is also in byte string pointed to by `str`.

Thus, if you really want to find *the whole* `searchterm` instead of *any character* of `searchterm` in `nameholder[i]`, you should use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) or [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

Also note that the operator `==` can not be used to compare the equality of two `char*` strings since it simply compare if the addresses are equal or not disregarding the string content. Use `strcmp()` instead.

Comment: I got it working it was a combination of different things, using strcmp() instead of strpbrk() was the first step in figuring it out though. When i used strcmp() it would return 1 as the result, so then i realize an extra character was being added to the original string input. So thanks for the help!